# How long can a human neuron live outside the body in a controlled environment?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, lab-techniques, cell-culture

Have there been any experiments that have kept neurons alive (stationary), without preserving methods such as freezing? If yes, then how long were the cells kept alive for?

Comment: Do you mean primary cultured neurons?

Comment: You can look into culture protocols. For example [this one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2557074/) suggests 7-10 days for culture maturation, then 2 weeks harvest time (scroll down to the last step). While a protocol won't tell you the longest time, it will give you a lower limit for the longest time. This is about nonhuman neurons of course, but there are also human cultures started from stem cells.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165027001004125) from 2001, they've got the survival time up to about a year on average. The trick is sealing the neuron inside a permeable membrane so you don't actually risk contamination when feeding. [This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2585802/) lays out experiments that take many weeks to perform, so as far as I can tell the science of keeping neurons alive has advanced to 'as long as I keep feeding them and nothing bad happens'.